# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid after laptop re-image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have run my first scaffold command to see if all is well, after the book purchase agile web development with rails.

```
rails generate scaffold product name:string
```

Upon loading WEBrick, I see the following error.

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ProductsController#index

Debugging steps carried out on my own:

1. db migration looks well formed (although who am I to review?)
2. loaded sqlite3 shell and cannot find the products table
3. gem file contains a gem 'sqlite3' line

Really new to Rails and have tried to solve this problem myself and struggling to connect the dots.

Any advice or support would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you run rake db:migrate after generating the scaffold?

Comment: Yes but that aborts, I get a message saying "rake aborted!", "Don't know how to build task db:migration"

Comment: The command is `rake db:migrate`, not db:migration

Comment: @rabusmar Can you post an answer below so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run `rake db:migrate` after generating the scaffold.